# Extracting rows that satisfy the condition of being within a datetime range

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe below, with a column of start dates and end dates for certain operations.
The dates are all in datetime.date, I iterate through both start and end date columns and check if the currentdate(also datetime type) is within the range. I posted my code below, I tried using both the bitwise operator along with the 'and' operator and they both give me errors.

```
df_current = [df_new[df_new['Start'] <= currentdate and currentdate <= df_new['End']]]
```

& Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'

and Error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `&` and not `and`. Try:

```
>>> df_current = df_new[df_new['Start'].le(currentdate) & df_new['End'].ge(currentdate)]
```

Comment: Hi, looks like it worked! Thanks a ton, just a quick question what are the .le and .ge functions?

Comment: [le](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) is "less than or equal to", same as the "<=" that you used. [ge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) is "greater than or equal to", equivalent to ">="

Comment: Ah yes I see, I'll go ahead and close the question now, thanks for the help! \

Comment: You could just "accept the answer" by clicking the green check mark next to it.